# Adding a new PointType in Point Cloud Library

Tags: point-cloud-library, point-clouds, ply-file-format

As a new user of PCL, I have to work with some ply files containing a class property (in addition to the label property).

I decided to modify the library to create a new PointType which may be called PointXYZLC;

So far, I have modified

1. the point_types.h file by adding a struct PointXYZLC (around l.103)
2. the point_types.h through POINT_CLOUD_REGISTER_POINT_STRUC(pcl::PointXYZLC ...) (around l.424)
3. the point_types.cpp for the std::ostream part.

However, I tested by creating a cloud with the class but the library failed to recognise the new class.

Any idea for further modifications?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used a trick to use the existing PointType classes. I reattributed the classes into labels and used pcl::PointXYZL